# Is there a Windows API to detect USB overcurrent?

Tags: c++, c, windows, usb

I'm trying to write an application that will take specific action when it detects an overcurrent condition on any USB port.

However, my googlefu is not able to come up with anything useful (though I can now tell you 101 ways to fix a USB overcurrent problem).

Is there are standard windows API to retrieve USB status info?
If not is there another/better way to detect USB overcurrent conditions programatically?

Comment: Googlefu white belt: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487341

Comment: As an engineer, I read the old title (USB over current) as `USB/I`. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff539687 you need to turn to the WDK (Window Driver Kit).